# Local search in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

I want to search in `NSMutableArray`. My code is:

```
arrCelebs=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Test 1",@"Test 2",@"Test 42",@"Test 5", nil];

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *arrString1 = txtSearch.text;
    NSRange tmprange;
    for (NSString *string in arrCelebs) {
        tmprange = [arrString1 rangeOfString:string];
        if (tmprange.location != NSNotFound) {
            NSLog(@"String found");
            break;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

If I enter "t" then it searches all the data and I want to add it to another array for display in a tableview.

Comment: check my answer..  i implemented exact you are searching..

Answer (score 7):

You can use the power of `NSPredicate`

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH[c] %@", textField.text];
NSArray *filteredArray = [arrCelebs filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Answer (score 3):

By using predicate you Can easily get the result efficiently.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@",  txtSearch.text];
    NSArray *ResultArray = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
arr_NewArray  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < [arr_YourArrayToSearch count]; i++)
{
     NSString *curString = [string lowercaseString];
     NSString *curStringInArray = [[arr_YourArrayToSearch objectAtIndex:i]lowercaseString];

     if (![curString rangeOfString:curStringSmall].location == NSNotFound)
     {
          [arr_NewArray addObject:[arr_YourArrayToSearch objectAtIndex:i]];
     }
 }
```

arr_NewArray will give you the array with data matched to your search string.

Answer (score 0):

```
arrCelebs=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Test 1",@"Test 2",@"Test 42",@"Test 5", nil];

_resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

NSString *arrString1 = txtSearch.text;
NSRange tmprange;
_resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(NSString *string in arrCelebs) {
        tmprange = [arrString1 rangeOfString:string];
        if (tmprange.location != NSNotFound) {
                 [_resultArray addObject:string];
        }
}
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This exact what you want...

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSMutableArray *resultAry = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(NSString *string in arrCelebs)
    {
        NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:textField.text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if(range.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            [resultAry addObject:string];
        }
    }
    yourTableAry=[resultAry mutableCopy];
    [yourTable reloadData];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**IF YOU work With `UITableView` then you cal also put this type of Logic.**

Take Two `NSMutableArray` and **add one array to  another array** in `ViewDidLoad` method such like,

```
self.listOfTemArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // array no - 1
self.ItemOfMainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"YorArrayList", nil]; // array no - 2 

[self.listOfTemArray addObjectsFromArray:self.ItemOfMainArray]; // add 2array to 1 array
```

**And Write following delegate Method of UISearchBar**

```
- (BOOL) textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)textField
 {
        NSString *name = @"";
        NSString *firstLetter = @"";

    if (self.listOfTemArray.count > 0)
         [self.listOfTemArray removeAllObjects];

        if ([searchText length] > 0)
        {
                for (int i = 0; i < [self.ItemOfMainArray count] ; i = i+1)
                {
                        name = [self.ItemOfMainArray objectAtIndex:i];

                        if (name.length >= searchText.length)
                        {
                                firstLetter = [name substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
                                //NSLog(@"%@",firstLetter);

                                if( [firstLetter caseInsensitiveCompare:searchText] == NSOrderedSame )
                                {
                                    // strings are equal except for possibly case
                                    [self.listOfTemArray addObject: [self.ItemOfMainArray objectAtIndex:i]];
                                    NSLog(@"=========> %@",self.listOfTemArray);
                                }
                         }
                 }
         }
         else
         {
             [self.listOfTemArray addObjectsFromArray:self.ItemOfMainArray ];
         }

        [self.tblView reloadData];
}
```

}

Output Show in your `Consol.`